# How do I minimize the code needed to perform matrix row operations in a python jupyter notebook? (using SymPy)

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, sympy, linear-algebra

Here is my code so far (edited screenshots into code cells)

```
from sympy import *
import copy
init_printing()
A = Matrix([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
A
```

```
#Functions for row operations
def rowSwap(A, i, j):
    B = A.elementary_row_op(op='n<->m',row1=i-1, row2=j-1)
    return B
def rowMultiply(A, i , c):
    B = A.elementary_row_op(op='n->kn',row=i-1, k=c)
    return B
def rowAddSubtract(A, i, c, j):
    B = A.elementary_row_op(op='n->n+km',row=i-1, k=c, row2=j-1) #use negative symbol to subtract
    return B
```

I am creating a matrix row operation calculator using sympy in a jupyter notebook, for linear algebra students. The catch is, the students have to enter the row operations themselves. I've created functions that they can use to perform row operations, however, I need assistance in editing them so students can write less code. Specifically, I would like them to be able to just type:

```
rowSwap(A, 1, 3)
```

and have the resulting matrix be displayed and saved, as opposed to entering:

```
A = rowSwap(A, 1, 3)
A
```

*The above two line way of doing it is the only way I've been able to get the result matrix to actually save so more steps can be done (i.e. performing operations to get to rref).

My attempt so far at a solution looks like this:

```
def rowSwap(A, i, j):
    A = A.elementary_row_op(op='n<->m',row1=i-1, row2=j-1)
    return A
def rowMultiply(A, i, c):
    A = A.elementary_row_op(op='n->kn',row=i-1, k=c)
    return A
def rowAddSubtract(A, i, c, j):
    A = A.elementary_row_op(op='n->n+km',row=i-1, k=c, row2=j-1) 
    return A
```

When calling a function it would look like this:

```
rowSwap(A, 1, 2)
```

```
rowMultiply(A, 1, 10)
```

Yes I was able to minimize the code needed to perform a single operation, however it is functionally useless since it does not actually save and update the matrix A. As when I call the rowMultiply function, it performs on the original matrix defined at the top, not the result shown of the cell just before it.

I come from a c++ background so dealing with objects in python is a bit foreign at the moment.
Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: how to ask a good question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code. Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, which text allows for (and pictures do not).

Comment: Modify the matrix in place rather than assigning to a local variable. You can still return the matrix after modifying it.

Comment: I think the reason for assigning the local variable is so that more than one row operation can be performed. Raheem says it's for linear algebra students learning row operations. So probably they need to get to reduced row echelon form, one step at a time. Each row operation gives a new matrix, and you want to perform the next row operation on the new matrix, not the original one. Can you store the new matrix without assigning it to a local variable?